# В чем разница между двумя вариантами создания ассоциации?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, activerecord

Какой вариант правильнее применять при создании ассоциации между например User и Post и какая на практике разница?

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
  @post.user_id = current_user[:id]
end
```

или

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если чуть поправить второй вариант:

```
@post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)
#              не build, а ^^^^^^
```

...то *никакой*.

**Но только при условии,** что `user_id` является внешним ключом пользователя в ассоциации `User#posts`, в соответствии с конвенциями Rails. Поэтому **первый вариант хуже**, потому что таким образом знание о внутреннем устройстве ассоциации расползается туда, где ему не место. Если оно изменится, придётся обновлять и там.

А так, можно рассматривать `current_user.posts`, как `Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)`, при этом `create` и `build` будут работать так же.

Если же поправлять в *обратную* сторону, то надо в первом варианте заменить `Post.create` на `Post.new` и добавить `@post.save` в конце.

---

---

Но мы живём в неидеальном мире! И в этом неидеальном мире есть **баги**. В частности, [`rails/rails#14003`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14003), из-за которого выполнение одного действия А (например, проверки `Model.all` на что-нибудь в валдиации или коллбэке) **внутри** действия Б (например, `Model.скоуп.create(...)`) можно **внезапно** обнаружить, что внутри А почему-то действует скоуп Б, в результате чего А выполняется *не как задумано*.

Шансов в это врезаться мало (и лечится это зачастую очень просто, вроде замены `create` на `new`/`build`&`save`), но стоит быть к этому готовым.